# How to make item always float left at top when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I write a page that show a list of div. When I click on any item, that item will show at left corner (left: 0; top: 0;). If you check my fiddle, click 1st item, I want the others item will show exactly position of 1st item. Please help.

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaoshun92/evpq8/embedded/result/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var li = $('#list li');

    $(li).on('click', function () {
        $(".big").not(this).removeClass("big");
        $(this).toggleClass("big");
    });
});
```

UPDATE: I also want them return back their original position when I click back again.

Comment: when you click them again do you want them to return to their original position?

Comment: On a sidenote, your fiddle isn't working in IE9

Comment: this not working with Jquery 1.10.1. Try 1.6

Comment: @haxxxton Yes, I want them return their original position

Comment: @haidinhtran check out either Rene-roth's solution or mine, depending upon how you want your animation to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so im assuming you would like your item to return to its original position.

what we need to do is add a `data` attribute on page load for each of the items so that we can revert them to their original positions later.

i also use `.is()` to help determine if an item needs to be moved/shrunk

Check it out

http://jsfiddle.net/evpq8/12/

Comment: This leaves an empty spot at the position your clicked li used to be.

Comment: the number of `li`s never changes.. i think you're seeing gaps due to the different heights of the wrapping `float` items

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evpq8/8/)

I solved your problem by creating a dummy li element at the position you want your floating li to be. It is then set to the height of the opened li, which gets an absolute position to be placed in the top left corner.

Add `position:absolute;` to `ul li.big`

Now we're going to create a dummy `<li class="placeholder"></li>` right after `<ul id="list">`

Give it the CSS definition

```
ul li.placeholder {
    display:none;
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
}
```

and add to your click event function:

```
if($(this).hasClass("big"))
 $('ul li.placeholder').css('display','block').height($(this).height());
else
 $('ul li.placeholder').css('display','none');
```

Of course this needs some tweaking (the height is calculated incorrectly due to the transition effect), but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list li').on('click', function () {
        $(".big").removeClass("big");
        var clone = $(this).addClass("big").clone();
        $(this).remove();
        $('#list').prepend(clone);
    });
});
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is you never get the enlarged div back in it's original position when you're done, unless you keep track of all the positions

Comment: I know but question was How to make item always float left at top when clicked?

Comment: @slash197 it my fault I will add more detail

Answer (score 0):

I just added a class to the first li element and swapped the htmls

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var li = $('#list li');
    $(li).on('click', function () {
        if ($(".firstItem").hasClass("big")) 
        {$(".firstItem").removeClass("big");}
            else
         {
            $(".firstItem").removeClass("big");

            var posItem = $(".firstItem").html();
            var curitem = $(this);
            $(".firstItem").html($(this).html());

            $(this).html(posItem);
            $(".firstItem").not(this).removeClass("big");

            $(".firstItem").toggleClass("big");
        } 

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kBZ4L/3/

Comment: you cant close the item by clicking on it again

Comment: yea, i planned to add another class and toggle it again, but just stopped attempting :D and i would suggest to use @ReneRoths answer , is a better one

Comment: your link in the above post hasnt changed

Comment: now clicking on a different item when one is already open doesnt swap them

Comment: @haxxxton please check now

Comment: Thank you it working but when you click the other, they will show up, not just close the current

Comment: @haidinhtran this doesnt appear to work correctly when clicking on a different item when one is already open

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy Hello, your solution is another way to make me understand what I am writing, this help me alot, thank you!